# Env. variable echoed different with " and without "

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'm learning about bash shell and environment variables.

I have tested echo a env. var surrounded by quotes and without them (I put it like it appears on my terminal):

```
user@pc:~$ echo "$BASE_DEPENDENCIES"
build-essential \
                   cmake           \
                   debhelper       \
                   mesa-utils      \
                   cppcheck        \
                   xsltproc        \
                   python-psutil   \
                   python          \
                   bc              \
                   netcat-openbsd  \
                   gnupg2          \
                   net-tools       \
                   locales
user@pc:~$ echo $BASE_DEPENDENCIES
build-essential \ cmake \ debhelper \ mesa-utils \ cppcheck \ xsltproc \ python-psutil \ python \ bc \ netcat-openbsd \ gnupg2 \ net-tools \ locales
```

The first one has new lines and spaces. The second one is only one line.

Why does it happen?

By the way, my system is an Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please indicate it by clicking the checkmark next to it; thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's a [sequence of expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) that bash does on inputs:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and filename expansion.

The unquoted version allows for [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) (with my emphasis):

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion that **did not occur within double quotes** for word splitting.

... and with a default value of `$IFS`, this means that `build-essential \(newline)(other spaces)cmake ...` turns into multiple words:

- `build-essential`
- `\`
- `cmake`
- ...

... effectively removing the newline character as well as all-but-one of each of the space characters.

Quoting the variable prevents word splitting (among other things).

Further reading:

- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/117549)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/117549)

Answer (score 1):

The shell separates parameters to commands with 1 or more whitespace (i.e., space, tab, newline) characters.  When you do not include quotes, the value of `$BASE_DEPENDENCIES` gets expanded to N parameters.  `echo` takes all its parameters and prints each of them separated by single spaces, so you get:

```
build-essential<space>\<space>cmake<space>\...
```

Quotes override the space-delimiting; everything within the quotes is passed as a single argument.  In that case, the value of `$BASE_DEPENDENCIES` gets passes a 1 parameter to `echo`.  `echo` then prints that one parameter as it was supplied (spaces, newlines, etc. intact).

To better understand, consider this simple shell function, which is equivalent to a command in this case:

```
foo() {
    for i in "${@}"; do
        echo "->'${i}'"
    done
}
```

Say I have a variable that looks like:

```
x="    1         2 3    4   "
```

Without quotes I get 4 arguments:

```
$ foo $x
->'1'
->'2'
->'3'
->'4'
```

With quotes I get only one:

```
$ foo "$x"
->'    1         2 3    4   '
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because quoting preserves whitespace. Compare with this:

```
# a=$(cal)
# echo $a
October 2017 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
# echo "$a"
    October 2017      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14  
15 16 17 18 19 20 21  
22 23 24 25 26 27 28  
29 30 31
```

First the `cal` command output is stored in `a`. Then it's printed without and with quoting. As you can see, quoting preserves whitespace, while no quoting breaks the text into *tokens*, which are separated by space.